# I need to display ordered list of files on my hard drive "c:" with the help of cmd. we should order files by size

Tags: cmd, directory

I need to display ordered list of files on my hard drive "c:". we should **order files by size**. When i do it, I have problem. *Every directory dispays grouped*. For example on my hard drive are 2 directories : 1-st- "55" and it has some files. 2-nd-"66" and that directory also has some files and 3 files. When i tried to display ordered list of files i saw next: first dispayed all 3 files from hard drive "\c" then displayed files from directory "55" and next to them dispalyed files from directory "66". How can i display all files and order them by size withot ftouping them by directories. I used command  **dir /a-d /s /o-s /b**

Answer (score 0):

As Mofi already mentioned, `dir` isn't built to do that. You have to build a list ("array") of the files and their size, then sort by size. I'm not sure if you need just the bare sorted list of files or their size too, so adapt the `echo` statement to your needs. You can simply reverse the sort order with `sort` parameter `/r`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set cnt=10000
for /r %%a in (*) do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  set "siz=          %%~za"
  set "file[!cnt!]=!siz:~-10! %%~fa"
)
REM for debug:   set file[
for /f "tokens=2,* delims= " %%a in ('set file[ ^| sort /+15') do (
  echo %%a - %%b
)
```

`set file[` lists all variables (I started with 10000 to get the variable names to the same length for `sort /+15` to work properly - adapt if you might have more than 89998 files),
`sort` can't handle natural numbers, it sorts strictly based on ASCII values, so we have to prepend the length with spaces  or zeroes and get all of them to the same length for `sort` to work "properly" (a.k.a to "human standards").
`sort /+15` starts sorting at the 15th character of each line and so ignores the variable name - adapt the `15` accordingly if you change `10000` or the `file[...]` variable name.
Also increase the number of spaces (currently 10) and the `10` in `:~-10` if you might have file sizes in the Gigabyte range.